# Moviepy can't add arabic subtitles python

Tags: python, python-3.x, video, arabic, moviepy

I am having an issue where i am unable to add arabic subtitles to an `mp4` video. My old laptop running `Ubuntu 20.04` can export video with arabic subtitles just fine. But on a new PC running `Ubuntu 20.04` i cant't seem to do the same thing.

Please have a look of the code below.

```
generator = lambda txt: TextClip(txt, font='Arial', fontsize=24, color='white')

subtitles = SubtitlesClip(final_subs, generator)

video = VideoFileClip("english.mp4")
result = CompositeVideoClip([video, subtitles.set_pos(('center','bottom'))])

result.write_videofile("output_english.mp4", fps=video.fps, temp_audiofile="temp-audio.m4a", codec="libx264", audio_codec="aac", threads=12, verbose=False)
```

Where this is the content of `final_subs`
[image: example]

The exported video has contains only the sentence punctuation, and not the Arabic text. I have tried other languages and they work fine, this is only the case with Arabic

The image below shows the punctuation subtitles without text.
[image: example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigating for a long time, I found that the new system doesnt have arabic fonts installed.

I have used the following command to install Microsoft arabic fonts.

```
sudo apt install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
sudo fc-cache -f
```

To verify installation run the following command.
`fc-match Arial`

The video was exported successfully with the Arabic subtitles, but needed to be reshaped because the arabic text was mirrored. I reshaped the text using `arabic_reshaper`.